# OpenCV Unable to detect circles

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am pretty new to OpenCV, but I wrote a programm that detects circles in a video for a school project. The Problem: In my video (.avi) there are some circles that are not being detected and some "things" that are definetely not circles but they ARE detected. I am using **OpenCV 3.0.0** on Windows 7 and my programming language is **C++**. Below you can find the code.

Any ideas how I could share the video file with you (maybe send e-mail on request)?

I think the problems are the parameters in the HoughCircles method.
Any suggestions how I can find the wanted circles? (I also posted a screenshot from a frame in the video (gray)).

[image]

As you can see I want to track the circles on the start/landing lane for planes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/Julian Büchel/Documents/Screen Video/Circle_Rotenburg.avi"); // open the video file for reading
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
    {
        cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per seconds of the video

    cout << "Frame per seconds : " << fps << endl;

    namedWindow("MyVideo", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL); //create a window called "MyVideo"
    namedWindow("Trackbar", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL); //create a window called "Trackbar"
    resizeWindow("MyVideo", 1200, 700);
    resizeWindow("Trackbar", 1200, 200);


    //These are the parameters for my HoughCircles method. I added sliders to be able to adjust them.
    int iSliderValue1 = 1;
    createTrackbar("dp", "Trackbar", &iSliderValue1, 4);

    int iSliderValue2 = 200;
    createTrackbar("Min. Distance", "Trackbar", &iSliderValue2, 500);

    int iSliderValue3 = 200;
    createTrackbar("P1", "Trackbar", &iSliderValue3, 500);

    int iSliderValue4 = 100;
    createTrackbar("P2", "Trackbar", &iSliderValue4, 500);

    int iSliderValue5 = 0;
    createTrackbar("Min.R", "Trackbar", &iSliderValue5, 40);

    int iSliderValue6 = 15;
    createTrackbar("Max.R", "Trackbar", &iSliderValue6, 50);

    while (1)
    {
        Mat frame, gray;

        bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video

        if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
        {
            cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
            waitKey(10000);
            break;
        }

        //Should I add the GaussianBlur? Right now you can see the circles more clear, but it takes up more CPU.
        cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        //GaussianBlur(gray, gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2);

        vector<Vec3f> circles; //Store the circles

        // Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
        //             src   vector   method            dp  dist p1   p2   miR maR 
        //HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 200, 200, 100, 25, 35);
        HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, iSliderValue1, iSliderValue2, iSliderValue3, iSliderValue4, iSliderValue5, iSliderValue6);
        //Draw circles
        for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
        {
            Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
            int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
            circle(gray, center, 3, Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1, 8, 0);// circle center     
            circle(gray, center, radius, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);// circle outside
            cout << "center : " << center << "\nradius : " << radius << endl;
        }

        imshow("MyVideo", gray); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window
        waitKey(25);//Make video slower/back to normal speed
        if (waitKey(30) == 27) //wait for 'esc' key press for 30 ms. If 'esc' key is pressed, break loop
        {
            cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Heres a link to the video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9CrbhLPFA3ZjF6Qlc4Zll1Rlk/view?usp=sharing I hope you can download it.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the parameters in you circle drawing? the first circle is a circle with radius 3 pixels. An all the circles are drawn gray, because you draw into a single channel grayscale image -> convert back to BGR/RGB/whatever.

Comment: to find a good canny/gradient parameter for the houghCircles function you could compute canny manually and display it. The circles should be visible in those canny images with same parameters as used for houghCircles, otherwise houghCircles has no chance to detect them, even if the other parameters are chosen well.

Comment: Thank you @LSA I have not tried that. It doesn't matter what color the circles are, if that is what you mean. But I will try to change the parameters in the draw method.

Comment: Thank you too @Micka I will try it and let you know.

Comment: Awesome it works! Is there a way to convert the canny image into gray?@Micka